# Siunitx and Cancel packages : bad alignment

Tags: siunitx, cancel

Cancel package disturbs Sunitx tabular alignment :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,cancel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3]|S[table-format=4]}
\cancel{14} & \cancel{213} \\
7 & 426 \\
3 & 852 \\
1 & 1 704 \\\hline
 & 2982
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick workaround would be to use `\cancel{\tablenum{14}} & \cancel{\tablenum{213}}`. This will extend the `\cancel` line to cover the invisible digits (the hundreds in `14` and the thousands in `213`).

Comment: Thank you. I will use it.